# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cuando envío la información de mi formulario a la base de datos, esta no me almacena ningún registro por la función `password_hash`. Solamente me tira el siguiente error:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Practica HTML\insertar.php on line 15

Les agradecería que me ayudaran, ya que ando atascado desde hace rato.

Esta es la conexión PHP:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
    try { 
        echo "datos enviados correctamente";
        $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
        if (!$sql) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($PDO->errorInfo());
        }
        else
        {
            $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
            $sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
            $sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
            $sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
            $sql->execute();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
               echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e ->getMessage();
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Prueba modificando esta línea:

```
$sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

De este modo:

```
$contrasenia = password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y finalmente en el método `bindParam()` pasa a la nueva variable así:

```
bindParam(':clave', $contrasenia)
```

Lo anterior debido a que:

**Explicación**

- El método `bindParam()` espera solo una variable con la cual interpolar su valor con el marcador de nombre que en este caso es `:nombre` y tu en cambio ahí mismo le estas intentando pasar la función `password_hash()` la cual no es una variable e intenta modificar el valor original de `$_POST['clave']`.
- Como el mismo error indica solo espera variables y no métodos de alguna clase, entonces lo mejor que puedes hacer es mover fuera de y asignar a una nueva variable la creación de la contraseña cifrada

De hecho si vamos mas allá y revisamos la [doc.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) checamos que:

Y cito:

> PDOStatement::bindParam — Vincula un parámetro al nombre de variable especificado

Por lo cual se cumple lo antes comentado, solo espera el paso de variables como referencia.

Comment: Me sigue dando lo mismo.

Comment: Moviste la creación de la contraseña fuera a otra variable y luego pasaste solo esa variable al `bindParam()` @MateoGomez

Comment: Si, seguí tus instrucciones, pero no me da ningún registro.

Comment: Checa si lo que agregué te sirve @MateoGomez

Comment: Es lo mismo. La tabla sigue sin registrar nada.

Comment: @MateoGomez ¿ No estarás mezclando las cosas ? Una cosa es el error que indicas, que **debería estar solucionado**, y otra es que obtengas o no los resultados esperados de la query. Si el error está solucionado, marca la respuesta como *aceptada* y **formula otra nueva pregunta** referida exclusivamente a la consulta.

Comment: Yo solo quiero poder encriptar las contraseñas en mi base de datos. Sigo sus instrucciones, y todo sigue igual. Es decir, sigue lanzándome que se tienen que pasar las variables por referencia y ahí seria.

Answer (score 1):

Si miramos la documentación de [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> #### public PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] ) : bool
>
> Vincula una variable de PHP a un parámetro de sustitución con nombre o de signo de interrogación correspondiente de la sentencia SQL que fue usada para preparar la sentencia. A diferencia de `PDOStatement::bindValue( )`, la variable es vinculada como una referencia y solamente será evaluada en el momento en el que se llame a `PDOStatement::execute()`.

El segundo argumento de la función **se pasa por referencia** (de ahí el `&` antepuesto al nombre). Sin embargo, tu le estás intentando pasar **un valor temporal**: el resultado de la llamada a la función `password_hash( )`.

La documentación deja claro la necesidad de la referencia: la variable pasada **no se evalúa hasta que se llame a `execute( )`**. Sin embargo, un valor temporal **se pierde al finalizar la instrucción en la que se crea**. En tu código, justo al finalizar la llamada a `bindParam( )`.

Tienes 2 soluciones:

- Usa una variable auxiliar:

  ```
  $pass = password_hash( $_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
  bindParam( ':clave', $pass )
  ```
- Usa `bindValue( )`:

  ```
  $sql->bindValue( ':clave', password_hash( $_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT ) );
  ```